# I'm trying to create a script that'll delete all files which have a bitrate less than 130 kbps

Tags: bash, mp3

to do that

```
#!/bin/bash
find ./ -name '*.mp3' | while read -r i; do
echo "----------------------------------------"
         if [ $(mp3info -x "$i" | grep Audio | awk '{print $2}') < 130 ]
         then
                read -p "Delete?  " -n 1 -r
                        if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
                        then
                        rm -f "$i" && echo "$i succesfully deleted!"
                        fi
        fi
echo "----------------------------------------"
done
```

it stops with this output:

```
Error opening MP3: /Like A Prayer/Madonna - Act Of Contrition.mp3: No such file or directory
```

It looks like there is an error with the filepath, cause the leading dot is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I think IFS is set to a value with ".".
Also, to compare integers, use [[ ]]:

```
#!/bin/bash

find ./ -name '*.mp3' | while IFS='' read -r i; do
    echo "----------------------------------------"
    if [[ $(mp3info -x "$i" | grep Audio | awk '{print $2}') -lt 130 ]]; then
        read -p "Delete?  " -n 1 -r
        if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then
            rm -f "$i" && echo "$i succesfully deleted!"
        fi
    fi
    echo "----------------------------------------"
done
```

Btw I think you have to add your file to the question:

```
        read -p "Delete $i? " -n 1 -r
```